# Google Analytics - Event Type goals, how to create a flow of all the event type goals

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, goals

I have 3 custom events created using google tag manager pushed into Google Analytics.

Event 1 - Event category is "Search"
Event 2 - Event Category is "Add to Basket"
Event 3 - Event Category is "Checkout".

What I want to achieve is I want the flow of the events according to user or any dimension, such that we can see which event is passing on to next event and after which event/where the users are dropped off/ cut off.
Example some users can navigate till checkout, but other users drop out after adding to cart.

How to track this in Google Analytics ?
I have tried this using "Event" type Goals.
Have created 3 goals (for 3 above mentioned events). But the problem I face here is I can only see one goal at a time in the "Goal" flow report. How to combine all events/ event type goals and see in "Goal" flow report or in Goals --> "Funnel visualization" ?

[image: Goal SetUp]

[image: Goal Flow report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events cannot be used for Goal Funnels except for GA360 accounts.

You would need to track virtual pageviews instead of events in order to use the virtual pageviews as funnel steps.

Comment: Thank you so much